# Copy DB2 TIMESTAMP from results with full precision

Tags: intellij-idea, db2

I recently upgraded to version `2016.3` from `2016.2`. To be specific, I am currently using:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3
Build #IU-163.7743.44, built on November 17, 2016
```

I am using the `DB2 (LUW)` driver provided by the IDE in the example below but I have tried to use my own drivers and still get the same results.

After I upgraded, if I try and copy a timestamp from the Results pane of the Database Console tool window I do not get the full precision. I was able to copy the full timestamp in the previous version.

For example, my results pane shows something like this:

[image]

And this is what it looks like when I paste it here after copying it from the results pane: `2017-04-12 10:42:11`

The only work around I have found it to cast the timestamp to a `CHAR` and then copy it from the results pane. This works but a pain especially since most of my queries end up being `SELECT *`.

[image]

Pasting: `2017-04-12-10.42.11.193944`

Anybody have any ideas on how to fix this? Workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug. Will be fixed in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.2 update. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Is there a ticket for this?

Comment: No ticket to track, it was fixed just now. You may expect the fix in the next IDE update.